# When combining two working sql statements with UNION ALL mysql becomes unresponsive

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in a MySQL database. One table contains default values and the other table contains override values and additions. I wrote two separate working SQL statements to select all elements from both and then when there is an override, replace the value of the default table.

```
SELECT
    d.id AS did, IFNULL(i.id, d.id) AS id, d.parent_id AS parent_id,
    IFNULL(i.content, d.content) AS content, d.order_id AS ord
  FROM cci d 
    LEFT JOIN instructions i ON d.order_id = i.order_id
      AND i.parent_id = d.parent_id
      AND i.specification_id = 'SOME ID'
  WHERE d.parent_id = 'SOME PARENT' AND d.specification_id = '1'
UNION ALL SELECT
    i.id AS did, i.id AS id, i.parent_id AS parent_id,
    i.content AS content, i.order_id AS ord
  FROM instructions i
  WHERE i.parent_id = 'SOME PARENT' 
    AND i.specification_id = 'SOME ID' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cci d WHERE d.order_id = i.order_id AND d.parent_id = i.parent_id)
```

Individually the two pieces work fine and as intended, but when I put them together MySQL spikes to 90% CPU and freezes up. Obviously something isn't working quite right. What would be causing such a freeze up and or is there something wrong with my statement?

Thanks

EDIT:

The output of EXPLAIN is:

```
id  | select_type          | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
1   | PRIMARY              | d          | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 105  | Using where
1   | PRIMARY              | i          | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4    |  
2   | UNION                | i          | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4    | Using where
3   | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | d          | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 105  | Using where
NULL| UNION RESULT         | <union1,2> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |
```

Comment: How many records are returned by each of the two queries?  Can you post the output of `EXPLAIN` for your `UNION` query?

Comment: I posted the result of EXPLAIN.

Comment: Do you not have *any* indexes defined on your tables?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the optimizer, which is switching to a non-optimal join strategy.

The problem is probably the "not in" in conjunction with the UNION ALL.

I think you can rewrite the query.  Here is a start:

```
SELECT (case when d.specification_id = '1' then d.id else i.id) AS did,
       ...
FROM cci d LEFT JOIN
     instructions i
     ON d.order_id = i.order_id  AND
        i.parent_id = d.parent_id AND
        i.specification_id = 'SOME ID' left outer join
     cci parent
     on d.parent_id = parent.parent_id
WHERE d.parent_id = 'SOME PARENT' AND d.specification_id in ('1', 'SOME ID')
```

Alternatively, using temporary tables would also solve your problem.

Comment: The code you presented gives the same output as the first half of the SQL statement I posted. The reason I need the second half is that there are some values that match the specification_id and the parent_id but do not match the order_id. The second select statement is supposed to look for those and adds them to the output. Is there a way to get these supplementary rows?